# Android app for recording, deciphering, analyzing, and keeping track of animal language

Tags: android, audio, language, audio-recording, social-networks

I was wondering whether there are any apps that allow you to place them in record, observe, analyze mode, and record the sounds made by an animal or by a bunch of animals.

In the case of a single animal:

- The app rearranges the recordings in a list.
- The app decides, where a sound starts and where a sound stops
- Each item in the list has a play button, for hearing the sound again, and an expand button. The expand button takes you to the list of all similar sounds which the app decides are the same sound (for instance, it could be, that if the sound is the same, the animal is using it to communicate, the same, thing, or perhaps a related concept). The user that then goes back to the bed room, can lie down, and relax. This way they can analyze all recording, also, using memory, to recall when the sound was recorded or heard, and try, using their visual imagination, to develop a better understanding, of, the communication, or what the communication night be (this, can be done, without looking at video (which could work as a sedative on the brain in terms of its ability to interact, integrate, and interrelate with the given sound concept, as recalled from memory, as the user moves and goes on (without being distracted by other video)).

This app could be used to develop a better human to animal communication.

- In fact, the app should also let you take notes, both for each sound recording, at the top of the list, as well as for the individual sounds under the expansion list (so as to be able to account for things to note in the recorded sound variations).
- The sound recording have time stamps, so you can figure out what was said when. Via a global button at the top of the app in the upper right hand side corner, you can rearrange all cominicable things in a single list in chronological order. This is a toggle button. This should be easy to program using references.

---

In the case of multiple animals:

This is the same as for single animal mode. But with an added layer:

The app, in this case:

Separates, the sounds, according to which animal is speaking, from a single sound.

Attempts to assign a different symbol using an animal type and animal number to each animal. When later used, the app can be placed in listening mode. The user can reassign true animal given names based on the animal type and animal number, and sound identification. As the animals speak quickly, the list is generated, and the user can click on the animal type animal number combination and assign an animal name (which can be kept in addition to the animal name and number, which could actually be an easier reference for people familiar with numbers, which, appear shorter, therefore are easily cognized and embedded in the brain, in comparison to longer names, which may go in conflict with animals whose sounds emitted, are, let us say, sharp, and short, (at least in the past majority, of, observed cases (at least the ones that incite familiarity in what I am familiar with).

Ok, so let us not reflect on whether speech is long and protracted or short and sharp.

Let us continue to analyze, the app, and how it should work.

---

To account for these cases, different sessions, can be arranged, each designating the session as a single animal or multiple animal session, and, a list, is the presented, in double columns, such as on Android phones, on Google Keep, for each session (with the layout for each session corresponding to the layout found in Google Keep notes, or on the miMind mind app software, found on the web).

- At this very top level, where sessions are present, the user can select, by clicking a "Select Sessions" button, the collection of all sessions, which can be analyzed together (as a single, combined, multi-animal, session), via an "Analyze Sessions" button that appears and can be clicked after the "Select Sessions" button is clicked.

Thank you for your development.

Thank you for your support.

Thank you for your app.

I would be very willing to download, and install, and even pay for this software, perhaps even including in the app a means to send requests to others to pay for the app on the user's behalf (which, could be, another plus).

This might not be necessary if the app was free.

In fact, I am even thinking, that many people would be willing to pay for, such an app.

In either case, it would be good for developers, especially developers concerned with animal welfare, to consider both options (or be part of a development fund, perhaps, crowdfunding). Users could simply download the app for free and users could decide to make donations (which, could, potentially, be extremely large). In the case where the user could ask for donations via posting a request for payment on a website, the user could also pay back by posting the result of their research on the website. However, I now feel that I am getting very negative. Probably, since people in research, which already have government, and private, funding, could specialize, in developing this app for free. A special website, could be linked, from the app, where users could discuss the fine point of the app, both from the users and the developer's point of view, and, from the animal's point of view as well (a special social section for animals where you could create your avatar based on your animal (if you had more than one animal, you could create multiple animal avatars, from within your real person avatar profile, and under each animal avatar which you could publish speech and language analysis and deciphered language (you can write what the animal is saying (it will be clear (once you analyze the sound, on your own, with your eyes closed, you will come up with real stuff (if not real, the sentiment will be nailed, and expressed, through, words)), you could publish these after registering them under your personal profile. Not all recordings and analyses would be made public, just the ones you wanted, and you could achieve special effects by publishing them in specific orders. When publishing them, you could also publish your own comment (so, what gets published, is the sound, the deciphering, and your own comment regards to this deciphering). In addition, you can have a fourth field, which only shows up on your private part of your profile, and is optionally added. This would allow you to place a private comment, on the entries. You can search the entries for text through a search lens.

This might be a better model.

Thank you for pointing, me, to such, an app.

Thank you.

Comment: TLDR; Is this for a specific species like dog or cats? Also, especially with dogs, the most natural common language to humans and dogs is body language, not the spoken word. I can talk to my dog, and other dogs with my body language, it's common to most canine species. This might apply to many other species too, like horses, cows etc...